# Remove weird space between column elements

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have the following layout:

[image: Sample layout]

I want to remove the space between the upper box and the buttons, so both appear to be in the same box.

Code:

```
        Column(
          children: [
            // RAW CONTENT
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxWidth: double.infinity,
                  maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                      _PREVIEW_MAX_HEIGHT_RATIO),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: MARGIN_LAT,
                    top: MARGIN_TOP,
                    right: MARGIN_LAT),
                child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black38),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: _ROUND_BORDER,
                            topRight: _ROUND_BORDER)),
                    child: Center(child: Text(_displayValue))),
              ),
            ),
            // CONTENT BUTTONS
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: MARGIN_LAT, top: 0, right: MARGIN_LAT),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        child: Text(_static.translate(
                            context, 'result_contentButton_raw')),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomLeft: _ROUND_BORDER)),
                        onPressed: () {}),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        child: Text(_static.translate(context,
                            'result_contentButton_displayValue')),
                        shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(),
                        onPressed: () {}),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        child: Text(_static.translate(
                            context, 'result_contentButton_copy')),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomRight: _ROUND_BORDER)),
                        onPressed: () {}),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: what about changing ` maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                      _PREVIEW_MAX_HEIGHT_RATIO),`

Comment: in addition, try dart devtools, which you can visualize the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin you notice is because of the default value for *materialTapTargetSize* on RaisedButton Widget.

To remove it, change it to ***MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap*** as follows:

```
Expanded(
    child: RaisedButton(
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        child: Text("This is an other text"),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: _ROUND_BORDER
            )
        ),
        onPressed: () {}
    ),
)
```